# C# get parent control (UserControl or Form) from inside a BindingSource extension method

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, controls, parent, bindingsource

I am creating an `Extension` method for the .net `BindingSource` object. Currently the method needs a `Control` passed in (this `Control` is the "main" `Control` which is normally a `UserControl` or a `Form`).

I would like how ever, to not have to pass this "parent" `Control` in. Is there a way to  find a `BindingSource` parent `Control`? I know there is a `Container` but that does not help me or at least I don't think it does.

Currently you call this method like below (C# `UserControl`):

```
//'new Object()' would be the data source
BindingSourceControlName.ExtMethodName(This, new Object());
```

I would like to dynamically get the parent `Control` from the `BindingSource` so that I could call the method like below (C# `UserControl`):

```
//'new Object()' would be the data source
BindingSourceControlName.ExtMethodName(new Object());
```

Is this even possible, maybe using reflection? Thank you for reading!

Comment: Are you instantiating the BindinSource (assigning it to BindingSourceControlName) yourself, or have you used the Designer to create the binding source?

Comment: The BindingSource is dragged and drop using the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BindingSource` doesn't have a "parent" control.  In fact, the `BindingSource` isn't bound to anything, like a control.  It is the source of data, for use in data binding.  It can be bound *to* by many targets.  What is bound to a `BindingSource` is defined in a `Binding` object which is contained in the bound control's `DataBindings` property.

i.e. you're looking at it in the wrong direction.  You can find the data bindings for a particular control, but you can't find that information from the `BindingSource`.

Maybe if you describe what you're trying to do, someone can provide some detail on that.